# UWP: Issues with SplitView with VisualStateManager

Tags: xaml, uwp, visualstatemanager

I have been struggling with `SplitView` control while trying to create a sample (and simple!) UW App. First the list of issues and then the code:

1. I am using `VisualStateManager` to control the `DisplayState` and `Pane` Visibility. So I do not use the corresponding attributes (`DisplayMode` and `IsPaneOpen`) in the XAML.
   *Issues Faced:*
   **a.** *Sometimes* the designer shows `Exception from HRESULT: 0x88000FA8`
   **b.** The Pane is always in `Closed` state - in Designer and in Runtime.
   **c.** I was also getting a runtime exception showing `Debugger` code but after restarting Visual Studio it's stopped.
2. If I add the two attributes in the XAML markup (commenting out `VisualStateManager`) then for the following combination the `Hamburger` button does not work: `IsPaneOpen="False" DisplayMode="Overlay"`. The code for the `Hamburger` button is plain vanilla - `MainSplitView.IsPaneOpen = !MainSplitView.IsPaneOpen;`

**Markup:**

```
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="721" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="Inline" />
                    <Setter Target="MainSplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="True" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="548" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="CompactOverlay" />
                    <Setter Target="MainSplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="True" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="Overlay" />
                    <Setter Target="MainSplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="False" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Name="HamBurgerButton" Background="Transparent" Padding="0,-6" Margin="12" Click="HamBurgerButton_Click">
            <FontIcon FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" 
                      Glyph="&#x2261;" FontSize="32" Margin="0,-8,0,0"/>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock RelativePanel.RightOf="HamBurgerButton" 
                   Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                   Text="Title"/>
        <SplitView x:Name="MainSplitView" PaneBackground="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                   RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.Below="HamBurgerButton" OpenPaneLength="200" CompactPaneLength="50">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Gray">
                    <AppBarButton x:Name="AboutButton" Icon="Important" IsCompact="True" Click="AboutButton_Click"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="About"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <SplitView.Content>
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
                    <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>
    </RelativePanel>
```

So can somebody either confirm that these issues can be replicated at their end (i.e. they are bugs) or that I am wrong somewhere or there are workarounds available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work...

```
<RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Name="HamBurgerButton" Background="Transparent" Padding="0,-6" Margin="12" Click="HamBurgerButton_Click">
        <FontIcon FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" 
              Glyph="&#x2261;" FontSize="32" Margin="0,-8,0,0"/>
    </Button>
    <TextBlock RelativePanel.RightOf="HamBurgerButton" 
           Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="5,0,0,0"
           Text="Title"/>
    <SplitView x:Name="MainSplitView" IsPaneOpen="False" PaneBackground="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
           RelativePanel.Below="HamBurgerButton" OpenPaneLength="200" CompactPaneLength="50">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Gray">
                <AppBarButton x:Name="AboutButton" Icon="Important" IsCompact="True" Click="AboutButton_Click"/>
                <TextBlock Text="About"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
                <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="721" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="Inline" />
                    <Setter Target="MainSplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="True" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="548" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="CompactOverlay" />
                    <Setter Target="MainSplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="True" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="Inline" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</RelativePanel>
```

The hamburger button did not work when width was between 0 and 548 because the mode is set to overlay... actually the pane had been opened and closed outside the frame...that's why it was not visible which made you to think that the button was not working. It isn't a bug in splitview... If it doesnt work comment...will help yo...

Comment: Yes, this code does work, Thank you and marking this as answer. But another unexplained thing is that I downloaded UWP samples from Github and ran the sample `XAMLResponsiveTechniques`. This has Overlay mode for 0->548 and it works perfectly! As you are pointing out is there any `z-index` kind of property which will make the Panel Overlay on the frame?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your Adaptive Trigger is working after all. Place it inside the relativePanel and see if it gets triggered.

```
<RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Name="HamBurgerButton" Background="Transparent" Padding="0,-6" Margin="12" Click="HamBurgerButton_Click">
        <FontIcon FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" 
                  Glyph="&#x2261;" FontSize="32" Margin="0,-8,0,0"/>
    </Button>
    <TextBlock RelativePanel.RightOf="HamBurgerButton" 
               Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="5,0,0,0"
               Text="Title"/>
    <SplitView x:Name="MainSplitView" PaneBackground="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
               RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
               RelativePanel.Below="HamBurgerButton" OpenPaneLength="200" CompactPaneLength="50">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Gray">
                <AppBarButton x:Name="AboutButton" Icon="Important" IsCompact="True" Click="AboutButton_Click"/>
                <TextBlock Text="About"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
                <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView><VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="721" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="MainSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="Inline" />
                <Setter Target="MainSplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="True" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="548" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="MainSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="CompactOverlay" />
                <Setter Target="MainSplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="True" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="MainSplitView.DisplayMode" Value="Overlay" />
                <Setter Target="MainSplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="False" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</RelativePanel>
```

Comment: Tried... same result! 1a and 1c have stopped but 1b and 2 - no change!

Comment: I also tried downgrading the Target version from build 10586 to build 10240 but no luck.

Comment: check with the attributes mentioned in the xaml ...i mean set the ispaneopen option to false or true in xaml. When min width is >0 then it will automatically change.

Comment: I found the following blog mentioning that this is a bug in `SplitView`, is this true? http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2015/12/06/SplitView-Bug-in-the-Universal-Windows-Platform-%28UWP%29.aspx

Comment: I am not sure about this. I have been using splitview and did not come across any problem so far. Check out this. [Guidelines for SplitView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn997787.aspx)...also set values to attributes ispaneopen and displaymode in xaml.

Comment: Okay, that means the Markup is all right... Probably my dev environment. That's why I had mentioned VS 2015 Update 1 since one of my friends not having installed Update 1 also cannot reproduce this. That's why I was wondering if Update 1 has introduced this bug. Anyways, will update if I find something.

Comment: Setting two attributes (any combination) in XAML with VisualStateManager markup as-is within RelativePanel makes no difference :(